# Cron job on Amazon EC2 medium tier Ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I am relatively new to managing servers. I have a medium tier Ubuntu EC2 instance. I have a php script reads from a database (not large number of entries, about 500), and for each record in the database transfers a file from the EC2 server to S3. The php script works as I would expect when I run it from the command line. When I try to run the same script as a cron job, it seems to end abruptly after about 100 entries.

I would appreciate any help on resolving this issue.

Thanks very much.
Vik

Answer (score 0):

I believe the setup of your cron-job redirects the `STDERR` (see an example below) to a file? If yes, then that should be the starting point of fixing your problem.

> example:
>
> 5 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/script.php > /path/to/logfile.txt 2>&1
> /path/to/logfile.txt should contain both output & the error (if any) on executing that script.